# How to make a Slick Carousel item become "current" via click on it?

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have two synchronised carousels: `A` and `B`.

`A` always displays 3 items. `B` always displays one item. Alternating between the items of `B` (via `swipe` or `pagination`), the items of `A` usually lose/gain the `slick-current` class. Ok. All right so far.

The problem is that I want `B` to switch between it's items when the user interacts with the items of `A`. But as `A` always displays all it's 3 items, it's not possible to swipe or use it's pagination. Therefore, `B` can't detect any changes to switch between it's own items.

I wonder if one can click on items of `A` so that they can lose/gain the "slick-current" status and `B` can detect that and alternate between it's own items.

Answer (score 0):

The official `focusOnSelect: true` option solved the problem.